# A Generalization of the Tate-Shafarevich/Tate/Fontaine-Mazur Conjectures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motives

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over a number field $k$. The Tate-Shafarevich conjecture says that the Tate-Shafarevich group of $A$ is finite.

A weakening of this conjecture states that the $\ell$-primary part of the Tate-Shafarevich group is finite for every $\ell$. By (a slight variant of) Proposition 5.4 of [Bloch-Kato's paper Tamagawa Numbers of Motives](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/refs/BKTamagawa.pdf), this finiteness is equivalent to the statement that the map $A(k) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} \to H^1_g(G_k,T_{\ell}(A))$ is an isomorphism. This latter group is the subset of $H^1(G_k,T_{\ell}(A))$ for which the resulting extension is unramified almost everywhere and de Rham at places above $\ell$ (equivalently, it is *geometric* in the sense of Fontaine and Mazur; see below for more on this). We note that $T_\ell(A) \cong H^1_{et}(A;\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})(1)$ as $\ell$-adic representations of $G_k$.

For a general smooth projective variety $X$ over $k$, there is a map $CH^d(X) \to H^{2d}_{et}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d))$. The kernel of the map to $H^{2d}_{et}(\overline{X};\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d))^{G_k}$, known as $CH^d(X)_0$, maps to $H^1(G_k,H^{2d-1}_{et}(\overline{X};\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d))$. In fact, its image lies in the subset $H^1_g(G_k,H^{2d-1}_{et}(\overline{X};\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d))$. One might then conjecture:

**Conjecture:** The map $$CH^d(X)_0 \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} \to H^1_g(G_k,H^{2d-1}_{et}(\overline{X};\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d)))$$ is surjective.

For $d=\mathrm{dim}(X)$ and $X$ an abelian variety, or $d=1$ and $X$ a curve, this is precisely the finiteness of the $\ell$-primary part of the Tate-Shafarevich group mentioned above.

Over number fields, the above map is expected to have trivial kernel (by a conjecture of Beilinson). But more generally, over arbitrary finitely generated fields, one might conjecture that the map from its kernel to $H^2_g(G_k,H^{2d-2}_{et}(\overline{X};\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d)))$, and so on, is surjective (with an appropriate definition of the local conditions).

This conjecture bears some resemblance to the Tate conjecture, which states that the map $CH^d(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} \to H^{2d}_{et}(\overline{X};\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d))^{G_k}$ is surjective. We can of course reformulate the Tate as the statement that the map from $CH^d(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} \to \mathrm{Hom}_{G_k}(\mathbb{Z}_{\ell},H^{2d}_{et}(\overline{X};\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}(d)))$ is surjective. Our new conjecture combined with the ordinary Tate conjecture is then the statement that $$CH^d(X) \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{\ell} \to Hom_{D(G_k)_g}(\mathbf{Z}_\ell, R\Gamma_{et}(\overline{X}, \mathbf{Z}_\ell)[2d](d))$$ is surjective, where $D(G_k)_g$ denotes the derived category of geometric $\ell$-adic $G_k$-representations.

As an idea on this front, could one deduce it as a consequence of the Tate conjecture, if, for example, one had enough injective Galois representations to dimension-shift between $\mathrm{Ext}^0$ and $\mathrm{Ext}^1$?

On the other hand, I wonder if one should see this more naturally as a generalization of the Fontaine-Mazur Conjecture. The Fontaine-Mazur conjecture says that any *irreducible* (and hence any semisimple) geometric $\ell$-adic Galois representation comes from geometry. This new set of conjectures combined with the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture itself would be precisely the statement that *every* geometric $\ell$-adic Galois representation, semisimple or not, comes from geometry.

This conjecture seems to be roughly Conjecture 5.3 of Bloch-Kato over number fields.

I'm curious whether:

1) My discussion is accurate? Is it true, for example, that this leads to the conjecture that every geometric Galois representation comes from geometry?

2) Has more progress has been made?

2a) More specifically it follow from the the Norm Residue Isomorphism Theorem, as 2.3.4 of [Bellaiche's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/BSDseminar/refs/BKintro.pdf) seems to claim?)

2b) Is my idea about it following from the Tate conjecture at all feasible?

3) Is it more naturally a generalization of the Tate conjecture or the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture, or both? Or the Tate-Shafarevich conjecture?

Comment: I am a bit confused about your generalisation of Fontaine-Mazur. Can't I write down uncountably many extensions of the 1-d trivial rep by the cyclotomic character all of which are de Rham and unram outside a finite set of primes? (say reps of Gal(Q-bar/Q) for simplicity). But only countably many can come from geometry.

Comment: @znt I suspect he actually wants to tensor his Chow groups with $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$ throughout, which will deal with the cardinality obstruction you mention.

Comment: @DavidCorwin I suspect that in the statement of your conjecture the lef-thand side should be $CH^d(X) \otimes \mathbf{Z}_\ell$, and the right-hand side should be $Hom_{D(G_k)_g}(\mathbf{Z}_\ell, R\Gamma_{et}(\overline{X}, \mathbf{Z}_\ell)[2d](d))$ (i.e. the whole cohomology complex of $X$, not just the $H^{2d}$ term).

Comment: However, I'm not sure what the correct definition of the category $D(G_k)_g$ should be, and it's not obvious that Homs in this category will map injectively to Homs in $D(G_k)$ (without the geometricity assumption). One sees this even for $k$ local (in the $\ell = p$ case): one can compute Ext groups in the category of filtered $(\varphi, N)$-modules over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ by some linear algebra, and one finds that $Ext^2(\mathbf{Q}_p, D_{\mathrm{st}}(V))$ doesn't always inject into $H^2(G_{\mathrm{Q}_p}, V)$ for $V$ semistable.

Comment: @David Loeffler -- yes, but the tensoring will also deal with the hope that every geometric representation comes from geometry :-) unless you allow ell-adic limits of such things -- but if you allow this then many non-geometric representations will also "come from geometry".

Comment: You should also be able to formulate this conjecture as a map to "absolute" etale cohomology $H^{2d}_{et}(X, \mathbb{Z}_l)$ (note the lack of base-change to the algebraic closure).

Comment: Yes Jesse, I had that in mind (and even partially referred to it), but as you can see, one would want some sort of geometricity constraint in our definition of absolute etale cohomology.

Comment: @David Loeffler: You're right, that's exactly what I meant in the derived setting

Comment: $T_\ell(A)$ is isomorphic to the dual of $H^1_{et}(A;\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})$.

Comment: @Adel: Yes, but by the Weil pairing/Poincare duality, it's also $H^1_{et}(\overline{A};\mathbb{Z}_{\ell})(1)$.